# Realizar busca em uma tabela ou outra com PHP

Tags: mysqli, php-7.1

O que eu gostaria é o seguinte: eu tenho duas tabelas, sendo `tabelaA` e `tabelaB`. Eu quero que o termo pesquisado se não encontrado em uma tabela, seja consultado na outra tabela. Não sei se tem algo que dê para juntar as duas tabelas ou como poderia acontecer isso. Então, em resumo, se eu digitar por celular, a pesquisa vai retornar os dados ou da tabela A ou da tabela B.

Comment: Você poderia fazer um if no resultado da query de busca da tabelaA, e se não encontrado, você busca na tabelaB com uma nova query!

Comment: Não comprometeria a performance do portal fazendo condições no sql?

Comment: acho que seria a unica opção, são duas tabelas diferentes, você vai ter que executar outra query!

Comment: Pois é, tentei aqui e deu certo. Obrigado!